# Calculate lagged values by a variable n

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a column with the variation of a price over a lagged value of price, but the parameter n of the lag function should be taken from a column in the dataframe (daysPrevWeek which indicates the lookback period to use with lag).

This is my dataframe which is grouped by ticker because I need to compute the lagged variation for every ticker in the df.

```
> df
# A tibble: 42 × 5
# Groups:   ticker [2]
   ticker date       price    volume daysPrevWeek
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <int>
 1 ALUA   2021-12-30  93   65074092.            7
 2 ALUA   2022-01-03  93.9 47821992.            7
 3 ALUA   2022-01-04  92.4 46178674.            7
 4 ALUA   2022-01-05  90.9 32271566             7
 5 ALUA   2022-01-06  89.2 41285726.            7
 6 ALUA   2022-01-07  89.9 17806296.            4
 7 ALUA   2022-01-10  89   20411427             7
 8 ALUA   2022-01-11  89.8 21928854.            7
 9 ALUA   2022-01-12  88.9 20604037.            7
10 ALUA   2022-01-13  90.8 34647124.            7
# … with 32 more rows
```

I've tried mutate like this:

```
> df %>% mutate(variation = price / lag(price, n = daysPrevWeek))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `variation = price/lag(price, n = daysPrevWeek)`.
ℹ In group 1: `ticker = "ALUA"`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! `n` must be a whole number, not an integer vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So I tried including rowwise() in order to "group" in a rowwise manner, but the variation results in NAs

```
> df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(variation = price / lag(price, n = daysPrevWeek))
# A tibble: 42 × 6
# Rowwise:  ticker
   ticker date       price    volume daysPrevWeek variation
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <int>     <dbl>
 1 ALUA   2021-12-30  93   65074092.            7        NA
 2 ALUA   2022-01-03  93.9 47821992.            7        NA
 3 ALUA   2022-01-04  92.4 46178674.            7        NA
 4 ALUA   2022-01-05  90.9 32271566             7        NA
 5 ALUA   2022-01-06  89.2 41285726.            7        NA
 6 ALUA   2022-01-07  89.9 17806296.            4        NA
 7 ALUA   2022-01-10  89   20411427             7        NA
 8 ALUA   2022-01-11  89.8 21928854.            7        NA
 9 ALUA   2022-01-12  88.9 20604037.            7        NA
10 ALUA   2022-01-13  90.8 34647124.            7        NA
# … with 32 more rows
```

I would appreciate some help on the matter.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dplyr::lag` doesn't support a vectorized `n=` argument, we can `sapply` (or `purrr::map_dbl` or similar) over it.

Sample data:

```r
df <- structure(list(ticker = c("ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA", "ALUA"), date = structure(c(18991, 18995, 18996, 18997, 18998, 18999, 19002, 19003, 19004, 19005), class = "Date"), price = c(93, 93.9, 92.4, 90.9, 89.2, 89.9, 89, 89.8, 88.9, 90.8), volume = c(65074092, 47821992, 46178674, 32271566, 41285726, 17806296, 20411427, 21928854, 20604037, 34647124), daysPrevWeek = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",  "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Since `lag` is going to return a vector, we need just one element from each return, so we'll need to extract one element per ... I'll use `diag` for this. (Full disclosure: there is likely a more efficient way to do this.)

The sample data isn't quite long enough to really dig into your `daysPrevWeek` variable, so I'll artifically create `nlag` here to mimic it so we can assess its performance in the whole frame. You will just use your `daysPrevWeek` and forgo creating/using `nlag`.

```r
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  mutate(
    nlag = sample(1:4, size=n(), replace=TRUE),
    volume_lagged = diag(sapply(nlag, function(n) dplyr::lag(volume, n=n)))
  )
#    ticker       date price   volume daysPrevWeek nlag volume_lagged
# 1    ALUA 2021-12-30  93.0 65074092            7    1            NA
# 2    ALUA 2022-01-03  93.9 47821992            7    1      65074092
# 3    ALUA 2022-01-04  92.4 46178674            7    1      47821992
# 4    ALUA 2022-01-05  90.9 32271566            7    1      46178674
# 5    ALUA 2022-01-06  89.2 41285726            7    2      46178674
# 6    ALUA 2022-01-07  89.9 17806296            4    4      47821992
# 7    ALUA 2022-01-10  89.0 20411427            7    2      41285726
# 8    ALUA 2022-01-11  89.8 21928854            7    2      17806296
# 9    ALUA 2022-01-12  88.9 20604037            7    1      21928854
# 10   ALUA 2022-01-13  90.8 34647124            7    4      17806296
```

Careful examination confirms that `volume_lagged` produces the correct number of lagged positions for each row. You can then use this in other calculations as needed.

Comment: diag sounds a little bit overkill but couldn't think of any other. Thanks, that works just great!