# Create a column with values from previous observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a column with the variation of a price over a previous value.

The previous value of the price over which the variation should be calculated corresponds to the date stated in the column `prevWeek`.

My data frame is grouped by ticker because I need to compute the lagged variation for every ticker in the df.

```
> df
# A tibble: 7,358 × 4
# Groups:   ticker [23]
   ticker date       price prevWeek  
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <date>    
 1 ALUA   2021-12-30  93   2021-12-23
 2 ALUA   2022-01-03  93.9 2021-12-27
 3 ALUA   2022-01-04  92.4 2021-12-28
 4 ALUA   2022-01-05  90.9 2021-12-29
 5 ALUA   2022-01-06  89.2 2021-12-30
 6 ALUA   2022-01-07  89.9 2021-12-30
 7 ALUA   2022-01-10  89   2022-01-03
 8 ALUA   2022-01-11  89.8 2022-01-04
 9 ALUA   2022-01-12  88.9 2022-01-05
10 ALUA   2022-01-13  90.8 2022-01-06
# … with 7,348 more rows
```

I think that maybe there's a SQL solution to this problem since I consider (maybe wrongly) that this pertains to a nested search.

Is there a way to do this in R?

I couldn't find any solution and tried to use lag, calculating the number of days between date and prevWeek and then using lag with that number as the n parameter, but there isn't an exact number of observations than days between dates. So this question [Calculate lagged values by a variable n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081783/calculate-lagged-values-by-a-variable-n), while correct, is not useful for my problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the expected output for the 10 rows shown?

Comment: Your code does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply looking to divide the value of `price` in the `ith` row by the price in the row where `date` corresponds to the value of `prevWeek` in the `ith` row, then simply join the tables:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, df, by=c("ticker", "prevWeek"="date")) %>% 
  mutate(price_ratio = price.x/price.y) %>% 
  select(ticker, price=price.x, prevWeek, price_ratio)
```

Output:

```
   ticker price   prevWeek price_ratio
1    ALUA  93.0 2021-12-23          NA
2    ALUA  93.9 2021-12-27          NA
3    ALUA  92.4 2021-12-28          NA
4    ALUA  90.9 2021-12-29          NA
5    ALUA  89.2 2021-12-30   0.9591398
6    ALUA  89.9 2021-12-30   0.9666667
7    ALUA  89.0 2022-01-03   0.9478168
8    ALUA  89.8 2022-01-04   0.9718615
9    ALUA  88.9 2022-01-05   0.9779978
10   ALUA  90.8 2022-01-06   1.0179372
```

Comment: Great. Need to dig into that since the full df has 3 columns, with 3 different dates to offset, and need to calculate the three price_ratio. Thanks!